# cannot find -lSDLmain

Tags: c++, sdl

i'm trying to use the SDL1.2 librairie with c++ files but, i can't compile.
i'm on windows and when i want to compile, the linking cannot be done.

i made a makefile :

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -I include
LDFLAGS = -L/lib -lmingw32 -lSDLmain -lSDL -lSDL_image -mwindows

Programme : main.o
    $(CC) main.o -o Programme $(LDFLAGS)

main.o : main.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c main.cpp -o main.o

clean :
    del -rf *.o

mrproper : clean
    del Programme
```

and here is my main.cpp :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <SDL/SDL.h>

void pause();


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    SDL_Surface *ecran = NULL, *imageDeFond = NULL;
    SDL_Rect positionFond;

    positionFond.x = 0;
    positionFond.y = 0;

    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);

    ecran = SDL_SetVideoMode(800, 600, 32, SDL_HWSURFACE);
    SDL_WM_SetCaption("Chargement d'images en SDL", NULL);

    imageDeFond = SDL_LoadBMP("lac_en_montagne.bmp");
    SDL_BlitSurface(imageDeFond, NULL, ecran, &positionFond);

    SDL_Flip(ecran);
    pause();

    SDL_FreeSurface(imageDeFond);
    SDL_Quit();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void pause()
{
    int continuer = 1;
    SDL_Event event;

    while (continuer)
    {
        SDL_WaitEvent(&event);
        switch(event.type)
        {
            case SDL_QUIT:
                continuer = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

and when i run the makefile with the command :

```
mingw32-make
```

here is the output :

```
C:\Users\summire\Desktop\a day in hell>mingw32-make
gcc main.o -o Programme -L/lib -lmingw32 -lSDLmain -lSDL -lSDL_image -mwindows
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lSDLmain
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lSDL
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lSDL_image
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make: *** [makefile:6: Programme] Error 1
```

can someone please explain me what am i doing wrong ?

also, here is my arborescence :

```
/
img/
    example1.png
include/
    SDL/
        all the .h files for SDL
lib/
    libSDL.a
    libSDLmain.a
src/
    (nothing yet)
```

Comment: `/lib` is a parody on absolute path; you don't want that `/` - and don't have it in your `-I`.

Comment: Not the answer, but why SDL1.2, if there is SDL2?

Comment: well @HolyBlackCat, i tried with SDL2 but i realized that i am more confortable with the 1.2 version. i just forgot to delete it

Comment: @keltar i removed the '/', i have "skipping incompatible lib/libSDL.dll.a when searching for -lSDL". and i tried to remove /lib but i have the same error as before. no more "skipping incompatible" but still "cannot find -lSDL"

Comment: @summire then your `libSDL.dll.a` is for wrong architecture (e.g. 64bit with 32bit toolchain, or vice versa)

Comment: @keltar i tried to replace it, but the error still the same